# Insert whitespaces in React Link doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, hyperlink, react-hooks

I'm using React with bootstrap :

```
  <div className='container'>
        <div className='row' style={{}}>
          Already have an account ? Please {' '} <Link to='/signin'> <span> {' '} Sign In </span></Link> !
        </div>
      </div>
```

and even without  :

```
 <div className='container'>
        <div className='row' style={{}}>
          Already have an account ? Please {' '} <Link to='/signin'>{' '} Sign In</Link> !
        </div>
      </div>
```

However the the whitespaces are always getting trimmed :

[image]

How can we fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use HTML entity ([ref](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)) instead

> `&nbsp;` for non non-breaking space

```
<div className='row' style={{}}>
  Already have an account ? Please &nbsp; <Link to='/signin'>Sign In</Link> !
</div>
```